# Load data of logged in account Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm developing an Android App which has Firebase Real-Time database and everthing is working well.

The users create their own account by Google login. But if an user log out and log in again, he can't load its data and he should create another instance of Firebase's database, like he is a new user.

There's a way to re-load own data of re-logged in account?

To be more explicit, my app, after the Google login, ask to write a string (the key of the node/room) and it should be automatic once re-logged in.

Comment: Are you using `push()` method when generating users key?

Comment: No. The key is set by user